# laravel queue timing out all the time

Tags: php, laravel, queue, laravel-5.5

I have successfully developed a laravel job in 5.5 locally using database queue, however moving the application to a testing server has thrown a constant issue.

Every job fails immediately and is placed in the failed jobs list.

The only error that is being returned is:

> has been attempted too many times or run too long. The job may have previously timed out

This is generated in the core worker.php through the function

markJobAsFailedIfAlreadyExceedsMaxAttempts($connectionName, $job, $maxTries)

I have 'tries' set to 5 in the job and the database config timeout is set longer than the execution timeout.

however it still fails as if it never tried in the first place.

this is the code that generates the error:

```
/**
 * Mark the given job as failed if it has exceeded the maximum allowed attempts.
 *
 * This will likely be because the job previously exceeded a timeout.
 *
 * @param  string  $connectionName
 * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\Job  $job
 * @param  int  $maxTries
 * @return void
 */
protected function markJobAsFailedIfAlreadyExceedsMaxAttempts($connectionName, $job, $maxTries)
{
    $maxTries = ! is_null($job->maxTries()) ? $job->maxTries() : $maxTries;

    $timeoutAt = $job->timeoutAt();

    if ($timeoutAt && Carbon::now()->getTimestamp() <= $timeoutAt) {
        return;
    }

    if (! $timeoutAt && ($maxTries === 0 || $job->attempts() <= $maxTries)) {
        return;
    }

    $this->failJob($connectionName, $job, $e = new MaxAttemptsExceededException(
        $job->resolveName().' has been attempted too many times or run too long. The job may have previously timed out.'
    ));

    throw $e;
}
```

Comment: Is this your code? or a laravel thing.  Disclaimer I  don't use laravel, I ask because `$maxTries` is only meaningful if `$timeoutAt` evaluates to false.  So if you have a `$timeoutAt` value, the second condition will never pass and return.

Comment: Also this line `$maxTries = ! is_null($job->maxTries()) ? $job->maxTries() : $maxTries;` seems to fly in the face of reason, when the function requires a `$maxTries`.  Meaning that the value of `$job->maxTries()` will override a value given directly to the function, which seems counter intuitive to me considering it's a required argument of the function.  But as I said I don't use laravel.  I only program PHP for like 7 years.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix its core Laravel not my code its just where the error is being reported at.

Comment: Well in anycase you haven't provided enough information, `I have 'tries' set to 5 in the job and the database config timeout is set longer than the execution timeout.`  When you say `tries` do you mean `$job->maxTries()` or the function argument, and what is the actual timeout.  I would do some reporting from in this function and see why those two conditions are false.  If either was true it would not fail.

Comment: when setting the job up you set the property 'tries' to a value in your controller. I have read a few other threads and some relating to this issue talk about when you run `artisan queue:work --timeout=60 --maxtries=6` from the command line , these values can accidentally be set to larger than the database timeout in the config.

Comment: Have you considered using a different queuing system, we use RabbitMq and it works awesome.

Comment: Ill have a look, but im too deep now in deadline to swap out

Comment: Sure, we use rabbit because it has very good failure recovery with persistent queues, and it provides a layer of separation, we could do the back-end workers in any language we want without changing the front end at all.  It even has a web based manager that is pretty feature full, and a Json HTTP api as well as a command line API..  They also have great tutorials even for PHP https://www.rabbitmq.com/

Comment: Here is a link to the tutorials,  https://www.rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html we been using it for almost 3 years in production and we run thousands of jobs, our server does 180k searches per minute, using Rabbit \ Sphinx and MongoDB and 3 servers...  Good luck, I wish I could help you more with Laravel.

Comment: What `queue` driver that you use in the `test server`? Same like your local?

Comment: Yes its all mirrored as far as I can tell, both using mysql database for queue driver